# Keras outputting integers rather than class names / labels?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, multiclass-classification

I've created a ANN using Keras to predict what class a specimin belongs in based on other variables. I used label encoding to turn these classes into integers (Dogs,cats,horse,etc) to use in the ANN. I then used model.predict to return an array of the class predictions, however they are in integer form (0,1,2,3,4..etc) rather than the actual class names I want (Dogs,cats,horses,etc).

Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simply use the label encoding in reverse?